# How to use OpenGL Hue, Brightness, Contrast for image

Tags: opengl

How to use OpenGL Hue, Brightness, Contrast for image

Comment: What "setColorHue" are you talking about? I'm pretty sure OpenGL doesn't include anything by that name (it uses a `gl` prefix on virtually all functions).

Comment: For example I have a picture and I want to use to edit UISLider Hue, brightness, contrast ... for picture. I had problems using Hue. You can help me on this issue. Sorry for my english ability slightly less.

Comment: Without knowing something about the function you're using to change hue, I'm not sure I can help much.

Comment: CLick Here : http://i.stack.imgur.com/vJjac.png
 On the other files it shows I do. Third bar shows UIslider Hue, brightness, contrast. And I just change the hue, brightness, contrast on the hair. I did the brightness, contrast.

Comment: I suppose you are using pixel shaders? It should be straightforward to apply the three operations in the pixel shader, just write out the math and apply it to the rgb values of your pixel.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in ability for OpenGL to handle HSV values. You can use shader logic to convert HSV to RGB internally, or just do it on the CPU for textures and such you pass to it. But there's no functionality to do it; it must be done manually.

Comment: I also thought about that. Thanks